# Create triangular meshing of a non rectangular shape in 2D in Python

Tags: python, mesh, finite-element-analysis, pymesh

Suppose I have a set of points defining a perimeter of a non rectangular shape in the 2d plane.

I need a function to create a triangular meshing where I can modify the number of triangle cells and return (x,y) coordinates of each cell.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a big topic - automatic mesh generation.  Generation of 2D triangular meshes has been an active area of research since the 1980s.  I'd recommend you search to see what Python libraries are available today.  Google is your friend: https://pypi.org/project/MeshPy/

Answer (score 5):

You should probably check out

- [dmsh](https://github.com/nschloe/dmsh)
- [pygmsh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh)/[Gmsh](http://gmsh.info/)
- [MeshPy](https://github.com/inducer/meshpy)

(I'm the author of dmsh and pygmsh.)

Comment: thank you Nico, I'll check that and return to you if I have some questions

Comment: Wow - looked at your GitHub repos.  Damned impressive.  If I were still doing FEA for a living I'd be using your libraries.

Comment: just asked: [Simple automated way to generate a mesh from my polygon geometry so I can apply FEM in an iterative way to optimize my design?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78055800/3904031)

Answer (score 2):

I poste what i did finally.
Some problems are found when working with Python3 . I advice to run on GoogleColab.

Source: https://github.com/inducer/meshpy/blob/master/examples/test_triangle.py

## Run in google colab if you have python3 and you do not want to downgrad to python2

```
!pip install Meshpy
!pip install pybind11
!pip install pyvtk

from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import

import meshpy.triangle as triangle
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
from six.moves import range
import matplotlib.pyplot as pt

def round_trip_connect(start, end):
    return [(i, i+1) for i in range(start, end)] + [(end, start)]



points = [(100,400),
          (400,400),
          (400,280),
          (320,270), 
          (320,160), 
          (120,160), 
          (120,250), 
          (100,250)]

facets = round_trip_connect(0, len(points)-1)

circ_start = len(points)
points.extend((3 * np.cos(angle), 3 * np.sin(angle)) for angle in np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 30, endpoint=False))

facets.extend(round_trip_connect(circ_start, len(points)-1))


def needs_refinement(vertices, area):
    bary = np.sum(np.array(vertices), axis=0)/3
    max_area = 5 + (la.norm(bary, np.inf)-1)*5
    return bool(area > max_area)

info = triangle.MeshInfo()
info.set_points(points)
info.set_holes([(0, 0)])
info.set_facets(facets)

mesh = triangle.build(info, refinement_func=needs_refinement)

mesh_points = np.array(mesh.points)
mesh_tris = np.array(mesh.elements)


pt.triplot(mesh_points[:, 0], mesh_points[:, 1], mesh_tris)
pt.show()

print (mesh_points)
```

Comment: Good idea to not downgrade.  Is this a porting issue for the GitHub repos?

Comment: I would urge you to look at the other two.  The GitHub models are fantastic.